# fs.watch get absolute file path on rename

Tags: node.js, fs, watch

I am using fs.watch. On a rename event, I would like to get the full path of file not only its file name. How can I do that. I am on macOS.

For example:

```
fs.watch('/A/myfile.txt', (eventType, filename) => {
    console.log(eventType)
    console.log(filename)
})
```

When I move `myfile.txt` from `/A` to `/B` I get a rename event but filename only gives me `myfile.txt` so I don't know where the file is anymore.

Comment: That's not really what `watch` is for - it's to look for changes at a path (file or directory), but not to report on the actions taken.  If the file is renamed into the path or out of it, you get the rename event, but it's out of scope for watch to track the action taken.  It is noting the change in the path.

Comment: But when I move it to somewhere else (after I moved it from ```A``` to ```B```) it still reports the `rename` event.